# JMeter cookie manager at the global level

Tags: java, cookies, jmeter

The JMeter documentation states that the cookie manager should be added at the Thread Group level. However what happens and/or what are the possible side effects of adding it at the Test Plan level? Am I correct in making the assumption all Thread Groups will pick up this global cookie manager and proceed as expected w/ no errors? Is this typically frowned upon? Just looking for a better understanding of how this works in JMeter.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used HTTP Cookie Manager added at the *Test Plan level* instead of *Test Group* one for any performance/load test-scenario WITHOUT any issues.

[Here](http://jmeter.512774.n5.nabble.com/HTTP-cookie-manager-td544523.html) an answer from Jmeter support:

> Is it possible to "propagate" cookies through different Thread Groups of the same Test Plan?
>
> No. JMeter threads are intended to
>   represent independent users, so cookies and variables are local to a
>   thread.

If you are really interested in you will get more information by enabling debug for your HTTP Cookie Manager:
`select Cookie Manager > click Help in jmeter's main menu > click Enable Debug.`
So you will find in jmeter.log debug info for Cookie Manager.

Comment: We do the same however, and this seems to be completely random, our app will throw exceptions noting the browser in use does not support cookies (that browser being JMeter). So I'm wondering if putting it at the global level is such a good idea after all.