# How to share cookie between two threads in jmeter

Tags: multithreading, cookies, jmeter

How to simulate a scenario where a user will login once and run parallel threads and log out .

a.login
b.performs action multiple times
c log out

Just wanted to know , how to share cookie between two threads.

Comment: What use case could you possibly be modeling by running several threads doing actions concurrently for one user? Wouldn't it be better to have each thread maintain its own cookies and model a single user?

Comment: Regardless, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825984/sharing-cookie-values-between-thread-groups-in-jmeter) may be helpful.