# Jmeter SessionId across all thread groups

Tags: jmeter

I am having different thread groups in my j-meter test plan and I want to
maintain same session id across all thread groups. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Please provide the result of your research, and at least one attempted solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try extract Session id with [Regular Expression Extractor](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm), and then use it in next thread groups

Comment: Also I found another answer with using BeanShell here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825984/sharing-cookie-values-between-thread-groups-in-jmeter