# Apache JMeter is propagating cookies between Thread Groups

Tags: multithreading, cookies, jmeter

I have this scenario on JMeter Test Plan :

```
1. Thread group 1

   a. HTTP Request Defaults

   b. HTTP Header Mananger

   c. HTTP Request <-- Authentication

   d. HTTP Request <-- Operation

   e. HTTP Cookie Manager

2. Thread group 2

   a. HTTP Request Defaults

   b. HTTP Header Mananger

   c. HTTP Request <-- Authentication

   d. HTTP Request <-- Operation

   e. HTTP Cookie Manager

3. Spline visualizer
4. View Results Tree
5. View Results in table
```

I want to perform the same operations on each thread group but with different sessions on each user can operate on the server. The problem is that the cookie is overwritten after the second Authentication Request and it the first is not kept on the first thread group.

Is this the normal behavior? How can I achieve to get two different cookies and continue using then on each thread independently?

I am using Apache JMeter 2.13.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing cookie values between thread groups in JMeter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825984/sharing-cookie-values-between-thread-groups-in-jmeter)

Comment: No. The link pointed by Kiril is not exactly what I want. I need to keep separate cookies with JMeter, not to share them. And I did what the documentation says to do.

Comment: In my defense, I run two instances of JMeter simultaneously with the same test with different login information and once the second instance logins, the firts one fails the new requests. So the problem is for JMeter between processes beyond threads.

Comment: @ag.albachicar, did you try marking the "Clear cookies each iteration?" in the **HTTP Cookie Manager**'s Options?